# Animating image loop in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to write a script for a loop with images in canvas element. What i try to do:

1. I want to load all images data like url captions and name first in ajax request (I should probably use `window.onload`) from json file
2. when image data is loading I want to show loading gif image, after that I want to show fist images from loaded json file in canvas element
3. this is main question when I click on button named "Click to match" I want to run function each will be draw random image in canvas element with animation - simple animation (I mean something like slot machine).

I have ajax request, function for random number, simple class for animation etc.

Logic is simple click button -> show several images -> stop on random image -> check image caption with selected type -> end (repeat again when you again click on a button)

I don't know how to put together my functions in one script.

**My json file**

```
[
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-1",
        "caption": "car"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-2",
        "caption": "bike"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-3",
        "caption": "quad"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-4",
        "caption": "truck"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-5",
        "caption": "pickup"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
        "filename": "example-6",
        "caption": "pogo"
      }
]
```

**HTML with JavaScript file**

```js
// ajax request
function createXHR() {
  if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if(typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
    if(typeof arguments.callee.activeXString != "string") {
      var versions = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp"],
          i, len;
      for(i=0, len=versions.length; i<len; i++) {
        try {
          new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
          arguments.callee.activeXString = versions[i];
          break;
        } catch (ex) {
          // skip
        }
      }
    }

    return new ActiveXObject(arguments.callee.activeXString);
  } else {
    throw new Error("No XHR object available.");
  }
}

var jsonUrl = "myJSON.json";
var xhr = createXHR();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
      // json file
      //var jsonArr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      alert("Request was unsuccessful: " + xhr.status);
    }
  }
};
xhr.open("get", jsonUrl, true);
xhr.send(null);
// how to "show first image in canwas" when all images will be loaded and in meanwhile show loading image?
/*
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // preload image
    new Image().src = "loading.gif"
  }, 1000);
};
*/


// show first image inside canvas
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var destX = 0;
    var destY = 0;
    context.drawImage(this, destX, destY);
  };
  // here should be firs image in json file
  imageObj.src = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/";
};


// random image to show
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var randomNumber = getRandomInt(1, 6);
//console.log(randomNumber);


// script for cheking image caption with selected value
function match() {
  var imageCaption = "car";
  var e = document.getElementById("selectList");
  var selectedObj = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if(selectedObj === "empty") {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "select your vehicle first";
  }
  else if(imageCaption == selectedObj && selectedObj != "empty") {
    //alert("match found");
    //console.log("match found");
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "match found";
  }
  else {
    //alert("not this time");
    //console.log("not this time");
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "not this time";
  }
  console.log(selectedObj);
}


//
// amination class
var Animation = function(canvasID) {
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.t = 0;
  this.timeInterval = 0;
  this.startTime = 0;
  this.lastTime = 0;
  this.frame = 0;
  this.animating = false;

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
};
// getContext method
Animation.prototype.getContext = function() {
  return this.context;
};
// getCanvas method
Animation.prototype.getCanvas = function() {
  return this.canvas;
};
// clear canvas method
Animation.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
};
// generating frame of animation method
Animation.prototype.setDrawStage = function() {
  this.drawStage = func;
};
Animation.prototype.isAnimating = function() {
  return this.animating;
};
// function get frame - number of frame
Animation.prototype.getFrame = function() {
  return this.frame;
};
// start animation method
Animation.prototype.start = function() {
  this.animating = true;
  var date = new Date();
  this.startTime = date.getTime();
  this.lastTime = this.startTime;

  if(this.drawStage !== undefined) {
    this.drawStage();
  }
  this.animationLoop();
};
// stop method - stop animation
Animation.prototype.stop = function() {
  this.animating = false;
};
// time interval method - return time in miliseconds between last and current animation frame
Animation.prototype.getTimeInterval = function() {
  return this.timeInterval;
};
// get time - return in miliseconds animation time
Animation.prototype.getTime = function() {
  return this.t;
};
// get fps method - retur current animation fps value
Animation.prototype.getFps = function() {
  return this.timeInterval > 0 ? 1000 / this.timeInterval : 0;
};
// animationLoop method - main animation loop
Animation.prototype.animationLoop = function() {
  var that = this;
  this.frame++;
  var date = new Date();
  var thisTime = date.getTime();
  this.timeInterval = thisTime - this.lastTime;
  this.t += this.timeInterval;
  this.lastTime = thisTime;

  if(this.drawStage !== undefined) {
    this.drawStage();
  }
  if(this.animating) {
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
      that.animationLoop();
    });
  }
};
//// animation class end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    <select id="selectList">
      <option value="empty">select vehicle</option>
      <option value="car">car</option>
      <option value="bike">bike</option>
      <option value="quad">quad</option>
      <option value="truck">truck</option>
      <option value="pickup">pickup</option>
      <option value="pogo">pogo</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Click to match" onClick="match()">
  </form>

  <p id="results"></p>
</body>
</html>
```